# Python- Regular express without order

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to extract for example 2 entities from a sentence. eg:

**str1 = 'i am tom and i have a car'**

I want to extract the word 'tom' or 'jack' as name if exist.

I also want to extract the word 'car' or 'bike' as property if exist

Now I can simply write 2 regular expressions:

```
re.search(r"(?P<name>tom|jack)", s).group('name')
re.search(r"(?P<property>car|bike)", s).group('property')
```

But I wonder if I can combine these two together.

The problem is I could not know the order of both name and property. So the following code

```
re.search(r"(?P<name>tom|jim).*(?P<property>car|bike)", s)
```

does not work for :

**'str2 = i have a car and i am tom'**

I tried to simply combine two order situation

```
re.search(r"(((?P<name>tom|jack).*(?P<property>car|bike))|((?P<property>car|bike).*(?P<name>tom|jack)))", s2)
```

it gives me "redefinition of group name" error unless I changed to

```
re.search(r"(((?P<name>tom|jack).*(?P<property>car|bike))|((?P<property2>car|bike).*(?P<name2>tom|jack)))", s2)
```

## Question

How can i write a regular express to extract tom/jack as name and car/bike as property without considering the order?

## Moreover

I don't want to simply list all the possible orders because it might be too many situations if i want to extract n kinds of entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but within lookarounds otherwise characters are consumed and engine pointer doesn't bother to go back for a new look up.

```
\A(?=.*(?P<name>tom|jack))(?=.*(?P<property>car|bike))
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/r3zwec/1)

Every pattern in a regex should match to lead a successful match. If they are not mandatory patterns make them optional.

Comment: [Partial match] Thanks it works but is that possible to match a sentence like "i have a car and i have no name" and get  the result like : group('property') = 'car' ,  group('name') = None.